# OpenMP workaround for barrier in loop

Tags: c, openmp

What I basically want to do is this:

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     const int n = 100;
>
>     #pragma omp parallel for
>     for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
>     {
>         int thread_ID = omp_get_thread_num();
>         printf("%d) work 1 %d\n", thread_ID, i);
>     #pragma omp barrier
>         printf("    %d) work 2 %d\n", thread_ID, i);
>     #pragma omp barrier
>     }
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

except we cannot put a barrier into a `parallel for` in OpenMP; it just cannot be done. However, it's possible to explicitly do the separation between the threads in order to make it work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>


int main()
{
    const int n = 100;
    int nthreads;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        // get the number of threads
        #pragma omp single
        {
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        }

        int thread_ID = omp_get_thread_num();

        // calculate which threads have to do one more iteration
        int one_more = thread_ID<(n%nthreads);
        int step = n/nthreads;
        int start, end;

        if(one_more){
            start = step*thread_ID + thread_ID;
            end = start + step + 1;
        }
        else{
            start = step*thread_ID + n%nthreads;
            end = start + step;
        }

        // the real work is here
        for (int i=start; i<start+step+1; i++)
        {
            if(i<end)
                printf("%d) work 1 %d\n", thread_ID, i);
        #pragma omp barrier
            if(i<end)
                printf("    %d) work 2 %d\n", thread_ID, i);
        #pragma omp barrier
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I find this a bit dirty and I would have preferred something cleaner. Does somebody have a better idea?

Comment: What would the first program mean, if it meant something?  `barrier` is used to ensure that the threads have all reached the same point in the code, but if that point is within a loop, threads may reach that point any number of times (including zero), and not necessarily the same number of times in all threads.  Is the intent supposed to be that at any given time, work1 isn't being done at the same time as work2?  It sounds like you just need a suitable mutex solution.  Perhaps a bit more explanation of your motivation (use case) might help?

Comment: It would mean something if a `barrier` meant "all thread **that did not terminate** must reach this before continuing" and if it was allowed to put the barrier in the parallel loop obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to synchronize two parts of your iteration and parallelize the each one of them independently. A good option is splitting the code in two:

```
int main()
{
  const int n = 100;

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
  #pragma omp for
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
      int thread_ID = omp_get_thread_num();
      printf("%d) work 1 %d\n", thread_ID, i);
  } // barrier (implicit, unless using 'nowait')

  #pragma omp for
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
      printf("    %d) work 2 %d\n", thread_ID, i);
  } // barrier
  } // omp parallel
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A really nice feature of this answer is that it will work the same way even if `#pragma omp` does nothing - which it could do if, for example, the code was compiled without the relevant compiler support flag such as `-fopenmp`.